# How can I write a Jekyll plugin that modifies the `site` object?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I want to write a Jekyll plugin that modifies the `site` object. The `site` object is available throughout the Jekyll build process. In Jekyll, the most direct way to add an attribute to it is to define it in the `_config.yml` file. That works in some cases, but I need to take it a step further.

The reason I am asking this question is because I need to do more than I can do in the context of a YAML file. I want to add a method to the `site` object. I assumed I'd only need to add the method to the `Site` class, but it isn't working.

Non-working plugin:

```
module Jekyll
  class Site
    def foo
      "foo"
    end
  end
end
```

I assumed from reading the Jekyll source and from how Ruby classes can be extended that the `site` object in Jekyll would have the new `foo` method, but it doesn't. For reference, [here is the Site Class in the Jekyll source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/site.rb).

This is as much a question required because of my poor ability to read the RUby code that Jekyll is constructed in as it is a question about Jekyll itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it without a plugin. Inspired by [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) you can craft a global variable to target your assets folder.

**_config.yml**

```
# can be '' or '/repositoryName'
baseurl: /repositoryName

ASSET_PATH : /assets
```

**_layouts/default.html**

```
---
front mater ...
---
{% capture ASSET_PATH %}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ ASSET_PATH }}{% endcapture %}
```

Then call assets from post or page :

```
<link href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

or

![img title]({{ ASSET_PATH }}/img/toto.jpg)
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion, I'm going to try that.

Comment: I believe I can solve my problem with your suggestion, but for the principle of it I want to build what I originally set out to, both to improve my understanding of Ruby and Jekyll.